# Big collections in DDD using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, domain-driven-design

I try to use DDD to describe domain model and code first approach on mapping to database tables with entity framework (using fluent api).
For example I have 2 entities: Clubs and Users. Club has many Users. And I need to add new User to Club.

```
class User 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Club Club { get; set; }
}

class Club
{
    public string ClubName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<User> Members { get; set; }

    public void AddNewMember(User user)
    {
        //..some logic and checks
        Members.Add(user);
    }
}
```

1. So, should I load all users collection in Club to add new and save? Or it's excessively?
2. What is the best way for modeling entities with big collections? Should I always load them? Or move then to another separate object?

Comment: can a user only belong to one club? also what invariants do u need to enforce?

Comment: @Marco, yes a user belong to one club only. and i need to check some rules - it's simple in my example, but i have doubts about working with collections of related entities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> should I load all users collection in Club to add new and save?

No, you can add a new `User` to `Club.Members` and EF will save the new user. It's not necessary to load the users first.

> What is the best way for modeling entities with big collections

That doesn't depend on the potential size of collections but on how you plan to access them. If there are `Club`s with thousands of `Users` there's no objection whatsoever if you'd want to query a small subset of users by a query like this:

```
from c in Clubs
from u in c.Users
where c.Type = "Golf" && u.Membership = "Gold"
select u
```

I always encourage using navigation properties. An EF entity model is for accessing a database in the first place. DDD concerns are secondary.

Of course you should probably always prevent queries in which all users of a club are loaded, unless you really need them.

Comment: I agree with this entirely

Comment: "No, you can add a new User to Club.Members and EF will save the new user. It's not necessary to load the users first." - What if you want to check to not to add user twice?

Comment: @dariol That's a different story. That would require "upsert" logic. But the question was "add new and save".

Answer (score 1):

Well it probably makes sense, based on what I can tell from your scenario, to use the `virtual` keyword for your collection and let Entity Framework lazy-load your collection

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj574232

Basically let Entity Framework do the work for you

Comment: that would be a waste unless he has logic that crosses against other members which i doubt is the case.

Comment: Well it directly answers both question 1 and 2.  I don't see how it is a waste?  His question isn't really about his Domain the way I read it, it is about how to use EF for loading related objects, the commonest way to do this is to use Lazy Loading unless there is a specific reason to 'turn it off' as the linked article puts it

Comment: well i can imagine a club having thousands of memebers. Would you really want to load the entire collection just to add a new user? I would hope not. honestly we do not have enough context to give him a pure answer

Comment: Well thousands isn't really that high. But I think Lazy Loading addresses the issue anyway, and the linq query will decide what is loaded and how much is retrieved and held in memory.  The entire collection would not be loaded to add a new user.  This is pretty much the point

Comment: Sometimes thouthands is not a lot. Maybe I don't need a collection of Users in Club entity, but just use direct save to DB context. But it's not a DDD way and I need to move logic from Club object to some "service"...

Comment: Hmm, let me see if I can simplify.  The way you have it at the moment, if you get a `Club` using, say, `var club = db.Clubs.Find(1)` EF would generate a query that fetches not only your club but also all of the related `Member`s.  If however you made the `ICollection` virtual (`public virtual ICollection<User> Members { get; set; }`) then when you fetch the `Club` then no members would be fetched.  If you then however wanted to get a `Member` from the club (`var member = club.Members.Where(m=>m.Name=="Backs")`) then that entity would be fetched with another query

Comment: db.Clubs.Find(1) will not automatically load all members. that is what eager loading is for.

Comment: Yes but at the moment his Club class doesn't use the virtual keyword, hence it DOES eagerly load the collection!

Comment: Sorry u have to tell ef to include collections when lazy loading is turned off

Comment: Marco I really am not sure what point you're trying to make. A combination of Gert's and my answer should help Backs understand what he needs to do though

Comment: i'm just trying to point out your understanding of lazy/eager loading is flawed unless i am missing something. not trying to be insulting just helpful.

Comment: Well I think your understanding is flawed. You don't turn lazy loading on and off, you use a virtual collection when you want something to be lazy loaded and non-virtual when you want eager loading. To implement Gert's suggestion you want lazy loading. If backs used his solution as is he would get eager loading

Comment: lol. actually here are the rules and i am done with this
Rules for lazy loading:
context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled should be true.
context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled should be true.
Navigation property should be defined as public, virtual. Context will NOT do lazy loading if the property is not define as virtual.

Comment: Yes well your additional (unrequired based on the question) information is available at the link I provided. The change Backs needed to make, as you have just agreed is to make the collection virtual. The models as they are are perfectly compatible with DDD so everything else you have stated in other comments and your answer and other comments has just served to confuse. Now I'm done

Comment: Guys, thank you very much for discussion. All your answers are usefull for me. The example is very simple, and therefore solution seems obvious. But real life is more complex and i think there is no "silver bullet" to solve all problems. I'll use combination of methods to achieve results in the most suitable way

Answer (score 1):

How about introducting a new domain concept 'Member'. Member could be an aggregate and have his own dedicated repo. or you simply turn off lazy loading with your original design and add it to its collection. this all depends on your business rules.

```
public class User
{
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
}

public class Member
{
    public Guid ClubId { get; set; }

    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
}

public class Club
{
    public Guid ClubId { get; set; }

    public Member RegisterMember(User user)
    {
        // Check business rules..

        return new Member { UserId = user.Id, ClubId = this.ClubId };
    }
}
```

Comment: That's interesting. I will thik how to implement this approach in the most appropriate way. Thank you for idea

Comment: But this is a many-many association, while the OP states that it's 1-many.

Comment: the OP mentioned DDD in the question title so really we need to figure out if he is really trying to use a pure domain model or a data model. you can use fluent api to configure this as a one to many. user most likely contains username and password / security stuff. while member is more of a domain concept. it could also be modeled as a VO but we need more context to determine all this